# Running .bat files from PATH in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

Running .bat files in Cygwin (bash or zsh) works when calling directly.

However, if I'm located at a different folder and I call the .bat file by relying on PATH variable, it will say `command not found`.

If I have a .bat file in environment PATH, how can I make Cygwin to execute it from any directory? This works for .exe files but apparently not for .bat files.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. I guess with _bat file_ , you mean a Windows CMD Batch file, right? But what do you mean by "calling directly"? Perhaps you could show a small example batch file, and how you "call it directly".

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to be more specific.  It *does* work for BAT files *and* EXE files.  What may be happening is that you are coincidentally using a name that is already taken by something earlier in your path.

If you have
PATH=C:\1;C:\2;C:\3

And you make a C:\3\foo.BAT

But there is already a C:\1\foo.EXE

Then when you type "foo", it will hit c:\1\foo.exe before finding c:\3\foo.bat.

This has plagued me from time to time.

I find the "which" command helpful in these situations.

Comment: PATH delimiter is `;` not `,`

Comment: Good catch. I was thinking verbally but writing as if it was code. Bad habit! :)

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin is able to execute `.exe` and `.bat` files based on Cygwin's **executable attribute** or **magic cookies** (`MZ` for `.exe` and `:\n` for `.bat`) in a file.

Take note at attribute `x`:

```
# printf '@echo OK' >bad.bat
# printf ':\n@echo OK' >good.bat
# ls -l *.bat
-rw-r--r--  bad.bat
-rwxr-xr-x  good.bat
```

Now `good.bat` is executable (according to Cygwin) and even completed via TAB in Bash.

If your mount point supports `acl` you can mark any file as executable:

```sh
chmod a+x my.bat
```